# ansible rsync with sudo passworded on remote host

Tags: ansible, synchronization

Im trying to use synchronize with ansible and it uses rsync.

I have this task :

`- name: Synchronization of src on the control machine to dest on the remote hosts become: yes ansible.posix.synchronize: src: ./ dest: "{{ var_app_path }}/"`

I get this error :

`fatal: [ip_adress]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "/usr/bin/rsync --delay-updates -F --compress --archive --rsh=/usr/bin/ssh -S none -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null --rsync-path=sudo rsync --out-format=<<CHANGED>>%i %n%L /builds/nickname/spa2023/ debian@ip_adress:/app/", "msg": "Warning: Permanently added 'ip_adress' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.\r\nsudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper\nsudo: a password is required\nrsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]\nrsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(228) [sender=3.2.3]\n", "rc": 12}`

Apparently, the command asks for a password but doesnt get the terminal to give the sudo password?

How do you resolve this? I am now using copy which is very very slow.

The command is run in a pipeline ci/cid:

> ansible-playbook -u $LOGIN -i "$SERVER_IP," --extra-vars
> "ansible_sudo_pass=$SUDO_PASSWORD" playbook.yml

Thank you

I have tried to run manully with ask-become

Answer (score 0):

So you could try to force the terminal.

As can be seen in the [SSH man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ssh.1.html):

> -t      Force pseudo-terminal allocation.  This can be used to
> execute arbitrary screen-based programs on a remote
> machine, which can be very useful, e.g. when implementing
> menu services.  Multiple -t options force tty allocation,
> even if ssh has no local tty.

The way to apply that on an Ansible SSH connection is managed in [ansible.builtin.ssh_connection](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/ssh_connection.html#parameters).
We can use the `ssh_args` option. It's default is `ssh_args = -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s` so let's just add out `-t`. You can start by testing it using your command.

`ansible-playbook -u $LOGIN -i "$SERVER_IP," --extra-vars "ansible_sudo_pass=$SUDO_PASSWORD ansible_ssh_common_args=' -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -t'" playbook.yml`

Comment: I tried your command and got the same error....

Comment: I apologize @kr1p.
I think I have a better idea. In `/etc/sudoers.d` what to the lines starting with `root`, `%sudo` and `%admin` say? Are they `ALL=(ALL) ALL` and `ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`?

Comment: i ve configured to put %sudo ALL=(ALL) ALL and Defaults rootpw

Comment: And it did not resolve the issue, right?

Comment: it's not a fix, it's the way i configured sudo to ask for passwords and what triggered the error in synchronize. so far i now use synchronize on directories where i dont need become:true ... but i cant use it on directory where sudo rights are needed

Comment: OK, new solution in coming. :)

Comment: Have you tried using `rsync`s `--password-file=` variable? If you want to be organized about it, you can copy the file to the machine in the task before and delete it after, or fill it with a variable from `ansible-vault` and remove it after.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method to avoid messing with passwords in an automated filetransfer/sync is to setup an account on the remote machine with SSH *publickey based* access. (Plenty of howto's available on how to set this up.)

If you don't want to allow publickey based access permanently you can also use Ansible to store the pubkey into the destination before the transfer and remove the (key) file after.

If you don't want to setup another account for this you might be able to *piggybag* on the Ansible account to do this. Usually this account is already using keybased SSH logins.

Once this has been setup, you can synchronice/rsync without issues.

An alternative (and even faster method) is using a git to pull the files from the repo on the remote machine.

Comment: thanks for bringing the git method. i can use it in pipelines but then i cant manually trigger the deployment not using the git pipeline to test my changes...